# How to solve this factorial equation?

Tags: factorial, binomial-distribution

How to solve this factorial equation?

$$\frac{n!}{(n-6)!} = 350.418$$

or to give you the original equation:

$$0.146 = \binom{n}{6} \times 0.45^6 \times 0.55^{n-6}$$

Sorry, but I've no idea about LaTex

Comment: Are we allowed to assume $n$ is an integer?

Comment: Perhaps you have in mind interpreting factorial for noninteger values of the argument using the [gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).  Alternatively you might think of $n!/(n-6)!$ as a descending product of six terms in $n$ as a polynomial.  Perhaps you should explain what motivates "the original equation" so Readers can better advise you.

Comment: Looking at the second equation, it seems that it is using the Binomial distribution and that the first equation does not corresponds to the same thing.

Comment: Regarding LaTex, you may find some examples in this [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: [WolframAlpha does not offer an integer solution to this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+for+n+in+C(n,6)+*+0.45%5E6+*+0.55%5E(n-6)+%3D+0.146). If the $0.146$ is merely an approximation, that could be a cause. The closest solution to an integer is $n \approx 16.889 \approx 17$ so that might be it?

Comment: @EeveTrainer:  How did you get that answer?  $\frac{17!}{11!} =8910720$.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork The factorial equation OP has presented us was mistaken in derivation, as noted by Ertxiem earlier. So instead of solving *that* for $n$, I told Wolfram to solve the binomial distribution thing OP included (since that's what he apparently seems to want the $n$ for).

Comment: All of your comments has helped me better understand the problem and I would thank you all. But I believe I need to better understand this question and then ask you all.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the binomial distribution under your parameters.  The closest answer is $n=17$ where the distribution value is $0.143168$:

[image]